# Strange behaviour of infinite sum (H[n]- Series[H[n]])

Tags: summation, series-expansion

**Bug report filed** 14.01.2020 A support case was created with the ID [CASE:4371991]

**EDIT**

It is easy to show that the workaround "limit of finite sum" proposed in the solution by user64494 leads to correct results for all cases shown here.

This points to a bug in `Sum[...,{n,1,inf}]`.

**Original post**

A strange observation can be made looking at infinite sum over the difference between the harmonic number and some terms of its asymptotic series

```
a=Series[HarmonicNumber[n], {n, \[Infinity], 4}] // Normal
(* EulerGamma + Log[n] + 1/(2 n) - 1/(12 n^2) + 1/(120 n^4)  *)
```

Consider the following expressions and system reactions

```
s1 = Sum[HarmonicNumber[n] - (EulerGamma + Log[n] + 1/(2 n)), {n, 
   1, \[Infinity]}]
(* 1/2 (1+EulerGamma-Log[2]-Log[\[Pi]]) *)
```

Ok, convergence to the correct value.
Now we try to improve the approximation

```
s2 = Sum[HarmonicNumber[
    n] - (EulerGamma + Log[n] + 1/(2 n) - 1/(12 n^2)), {n, 
   1, \[Infinity]}]
```

> "Sum::div: "Sum does not converge. "

Strange: a better approximation leads to divergence of the sum

```
s3 = Sum[HarmonicNumber[
    n] - (EulerGamma + Log[n] + 1/(2 n) - 1/(12 n^2) + 1/(
     120 n^4)), {n, 1, \[Infinity]}]
```

> "Sum::div: "Sum does not converge. "

Similarly, divergence to 4th second order.

```
s4 = Sum[HarmonicNumber[n] - (EulerGamma + Log[n] + 1/(2 n) - (0*1)/(12 n^2) + 1/(120 n^4)), {n, 1, \[Infinity]}]
(* 1/2+EulerGamma/2-\[Pi]^4/10800+1/2 (-Log[2]-Log[\[Pi]]) *)
```

Strange: taking the 4th order and dropping the 2nd order leads to convergence to the correct value

This is version 10.0. In 8.0 `s4` is also divergent.

Answer (score 2):

Mathematica 12.0 also claims the divergence of `s2`. I think the defect under consideration is not hard in view of  a workaround

```
Sum[HarmonicNumber[n] - (EulerGamma + Log[n] + 1/(2 n) - 1/(12 n^2)), {n, 1, a}, 
Assumptions -> a > 1]
```

> 1/12 (-12-12 a-12 a EulerGamma-6 HarmonicNumber[a]+12 HarmonicNumber[1+a]+12 a HarmonicNumber[1+a]+HarmonicNumber[a,2]-12 Log[Pochhammer[1,a]])

```
Limit[%, a -> Infinity]
```

> 1/72 (36 + 36 EulerGamma + [Pi]^2 - 36 Log[2 [Pi]])

Comment: @ user64494 +1 for the proposal which narows down the location of the bug. I have taken the freedom to incorporate your workaround as in EDIT in m OP.